# How to integrate a function when the lower limit is unknown?

Tags: r, numerical-integration

I use RStudio for university. And I got this task where I need help:

Response times of people were measured. The following density function was found:

f (x) = 0.62 * (1 / x)

only positive reaction times between 1 and 5 seconds were measured.
In which interval [c, 5] do the top 30 percent of the response times fall? Calculate c!

Normally I would integrate in this way:

```
integrand_2 <- function(x) {0.62 * (1/x)}

integrate(integrand, lower = , upper = 5)
```

But as you can see, I have the problem that the lower limit is unknown. How can I find this unknown lower limit (c)?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this?

```
f <- function(z) integrate(function(x) 0.62 / x, z, 5)$value - 0.3
res <- uniroot(f, c(1, 5))$root
```

then we have

```
> res
[1] 3.081973

> integrate(function(x) 0.62 / x, res, 5)$value
[1] 0.2999982
```

Comment: Thank you! Your answer was helpful. I got the correct answer for this task. But I have a question why did you write -0.3 in the f function?

Comment: @missnobodycares I need to solve zeros of `f`, which gives the lower limit `z` such that the integration from `z` to `5` is `0.3`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way, but not with the result in [ThomasIsCoding's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67912108/8245406).

```
pdf <- function(x) {
  0.62/x
}
cdf <- function(x){
  integrate(pdf, lower = 1, upper = x)$value
}

u <- uniroot(function(x) cdf(x) - 0.7, c(1, 5))
u$root
#[1] 3.092671

1 - cdf(u$root)
#[1] 0.2999982
```

But if the correct normalizing constant `1/log(5)` is used instead of the rounded value `0.62`, the result becomes closer.

```
pdf <- function(x) {
  1/log(5)/x
}
# Same cdf
u <- uniroot(function(x) cdf(x) - 0.7, c(1, 5))
u$root
#[1] 3.085178

1 - cdf(u$root)
#[1] 0.2999982
```